# How to select a field from html table using Selenium web driver in java

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

In my web page i have a html table and it contains multiple radio button. I want to select one radio button. So far i am able to find the values from the table but not able to select. This is my code: I am getting error on syntax aname.click();
Error is "The method click() is undefined for the type String"

```
import java.io.*;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.Select;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.ie.InternetExplorerDriver;
import java.util.List;  
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

      public class SendTxn1 {

    static WebDriver d1=null;

        public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, InterruptedException
        {
        File file1=new File("C:\\Selenium\\IEDriverServer_Win32_2.35.3\\IEDriverServer.exe");
        System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver",file1.getAbsolutePath());

        d1= new InternetExplorerDriver();
        d1.get("http://10.00.00.107/");


             WebElement table_element = d1.findElement(By.id("tblSendMoneyPayoutAgents"));
             List<WebElement> tbl_rows=table_element.findElements(By.xpath("id('tblSendMoneyPayoutAgents')/tbody/tr"));

             System.out.println("NUMBER OF ROWS IN THIS TABLE = "+tbl_rows.size());
             int row_num,col_num;

            row_num=1;
             col_num=1;
             String aname; 

                 for(WebElement trElement : tbl_rows)
                 {
                     List<WebElement> tbl_col=trElement.findElements(By.xpath("td"));


                        for(WebElement tdElement : tbl_col)
                         {
                            aname = tdElement.getText();

                             if(aname.equals("VNM - VN Shop Herat"))

                                      aname.click()l
                             break;               

                            System.out.println(aname);
                            col_num++;
                        }

                        row_num++;
                }                 
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you provide your html code?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use `executeScript` to select your radio button. This method executes a javascript string. Think of it as doing `eval`, but from Selenium. Depending on what version of Selenium you are using, you can cast your webdriver to a `JavascriptExecutor`, and then call `executeScript`, e.g.

```
((JavascriptExecutor) d1).executeScript("alert('replace the alert with the code to select your radio button');");
```

**EDIT**

If you don't want to use `executeScript`, you need to get the `WebElement` that corresponds to your radio button and then call its `click` method. In your case, you are trying to call click on the string returned by `getText`, hence your error :). So you are missing one more step that selects the radio buttons from your table cell.

Something along the lines of (the xpath query might be wrong)

```
List<WebElement> radio_buttons = tdElement.findElements(By.xpath('input[type=radio]'));
```

**EDIT 2**

To spell out the answer for you in copy-paste-able form, replace

```
aname = tdElement.getText();
if(aname.equals("VNM - VN Shop Herat"))
  aname.click();
```

with

```
if(tdElement.getText().equals("VNM - VN Shop Herat")) {
   List<WebElement> radio_buttons = tdElement.findElements(By.xpath('input[type=radio]'));
   for(WebElement radio : radio_buttons) {
         //now check which radio you want to click
   }
}
```

Comment: i tried with that as well, and now i am getting error as "Type mismatch: cannot convert from String to WebElement

change type of aname to string"

Comment: I don't know what you changed, but you shouldn't be doing anything with your aname variable, other than print it! You need to get the WebElement for the radio button and then perform click operations on it. To get the WebElement for your radio button, you can either get it by the element id (if you know the id of the radio button), or via an xpath query.

Comment: oh i changed the variable type form string to WebElement.

Comment: Clearly this is not right! Did you look at my answer and its edits at all? Your line "aname = tdElement.getText();" assigns a **string** value to the variable aname. Simply changing the type of aname does not change the fact that the method "getText" returns a string!